# Kitchen-proof ebook reader for recipes

Tags: tablet, e-reader

I'm looking for an e-book reader or tablet for use in a kitchen.  Most of the recipes I use are in electronic form (saved web pages, scans of recipe cards, etc.), and running back and forth between the kitchen and the computer room while cooking is a bit annoying.

1. Must be kitchen-proof.  That means surviving grease splatters, spills of boiling water, and the occasional dropped knife.
2. Supports HTML, PDF, and either CBZ or folders full of images.
3. Must be able to put files on it from Linux.
4. Prefer an e-ink display.  I've found that backlit displays aren't very good when you're shifting your attention between the display and something else.
5. No real price requirements, but less expensive is better.  Something that meets requirements 2-4 for less than $30 is also an option, because at that price, I can afford to replace it every time it gets destroyed.

Comment: Not an answer: Would you consider a case with screen protector?

Comment: If the case meets the requirements for kitchen-proofing, yes.

Comment: ...a laserprinter and a 3-ring binder. Plastic page protectors for the major mess protection if you need that. This is one of those places where old tech is better suited to the task.

Comment: You could look at Qooq tablet but i don't know if they sell outside EU. (http://www.qooq.com/tablette/en)

Comment: Here you go mark, check this out it's an ip67 rated e-reader https://gl.kobobooks.com/ it the h2o moddel. i would recommend the screen cover (i beleave its not expensive) and it protects it agains the point of the knife fall case or the occasional side stab. i think you can load it up via usb but you can alway run wine with it.

Answer (score 2):

The Kobo Aura H2o is what you need. its a pater proof e-reader with e-ink display and can survive 30 min in 1 meter deep water. It also has a hd display and supports almost all formats under the sun. I believe it's about 180 dollars. There is a case accessory that snaps off by the looks of it. This cover makes it so you don't stab the unit it self but the case. It has an online books store and can be loaded up with microUSB according to their site. You might need to run whine with it.

Good luck with the search I hope this helps you.

[Link to product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N9ZVN90)

Overall it's a high res e-paper display tables e-reader with some cool features and is not very expensive.

Comment: Fair warning: Amazon affiliate links are rewritten by the Stack Exchange engine to SE's own affiliate links.

Comment: Sorry @ArtOfCode, didn't know but its not a affilate link. there isn't even amazon in the netherlands and would have no intend of doing so. I'm here trying to help not to profite about it. otherwise i would be working at a callcenter and not as a developer

Comment: Also Thank you for correcting me so often. it must be frustrating to have to correct me so often.

Comment: Oh I'm not worried about you profiting from here, people paste them by accident a fair amount. It can just be useful to know that the engine rewrites them.